# Javascript function not modifying html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with a Javascript function. It is supposed to check if two input boxes in a form have the same value, using an `if` statement.

HTML:

```
<form action="confirm_account.php" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="checkpassword()">

<p style="font-family:latine;">Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="font-family:latine;" required>
</p>
<br><br>
<p style="font-family:latine;">Re-enter Password: <input type="password" name="password-reenter" id="password-reenter" style="font-family:latine;" required> </p>
<span id="password-warning" style="color:red; font-weight:bold;"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var password2 = document.getElementById("password-reenter").value;
function checkpassword(){
   if('password' == 'password2'){
       document.getElementById("form").action = "confirm_account.php";
       document.getElementById("password-warning").innerHTML = "";
}
  else{
    document.getElementById("password-warning").innerHTML = "The passwords do not match, please re-enter the password.";
    document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = "return false";
}
};
```

The warning message shows up, but the `onsubmit` is not modified.

Comment: `if('password' == 'password2')` you're not checking password and password2, instead checking two strings :)

Comment: what happens if you try:  document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = null;

Comment: replace `document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = "return false";` with `return false;`

Comment: I got rid of the quotes, but the now function does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```js
function checkpassword() {
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var password2 = document.getElementById("password-reenter").value;

  if (password === password2) {
    document.getElementById("form").action = "confirm_account.php";
    document.getElementById("password-warning").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("password-success").innerHTML = "The passwords match! Well done!";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("password-warning").innerHTML = "The passwords do not match, please re-enter the password.";
    document.getElementById("password-success").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("password-reenter").focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="return checkpassword()">

  <p style="font-family:latine;">Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="font-family:latine;" required>
  </p>

  <br>
  <p style="font-family:latine;">Re-enter Password:
    <input type="password" name="password-reenter" id="password-reenter" style="font-family:latine;" required>
  </p>

  <p>
    <span id="password-success" style="color:green;"></span>
    <span id="password-warning" style="color:red; "></span>

    <input type="submit" name="btnSave" value="Try it">
</form>
```

Comment: I don't need the alerts, do I?

Comment: okay, one last thing. How can I make the "reenter password" box receive focus if the passwords don't match?

Comment: You can achieve it easily with the `focus()` method. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var password2 = document.getElementById("password-reenter").value;
```

In your `if` condition, you're not checking `password` and `password2` instead you are actually checking the strings.

It should be

```
 if(password === password2){
```

And `onsubmit` is an event and you can't assign string to it. As you're calling `checkpassword` from onsubmit of form. To prevent form submission just `return false`.

```
var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
var password2 = document.getElementById("password-reenter").value;
function checkpassword(){
   if(password === password2){
       document.getElementById("password-warning").innerHTML = "";
   }
  else{
    document.getElementById("password-warning").innerHTML = "The passwords do not match, please re-enter the password.";
    return false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Better if you use ===

Comment: @mohamedrias, I want the variables to be global variables.

Comment: @yak613 Okay. But if you want to prevent the form from submission, just `return false`. You can't assign a string as event handler

Comment: `onsubmit` is an attribute of the form, isn't it?

Comment: @yak613 It's an event and you can bind it to form as an attribute

Comment: So now the message shows up but the `return false` doesn't work. I put the variables inside the function `checkpassword`.

Comment: Did the form submit now?